# É possível fazer conexões com Python sem utilizar os pacotes da linguagem?

Tags: python, socket

Eu utilizo vários modulos para me conectar a sites com Python, como o *socket* e o *urllib*, mas, sem os módulos, como seria feita essa conexão? Eu tenho conhecimento de que esse é um procedimento complexo e que envolve outras linguagens de programação, mas tenho curiosidade a respeito de como a linguagem de programação interage diretamente com a internet.

Comment: Reescrevendo todo o código dos módulos do zero, incluindo código em C. Por quê precisa disso?

Comment: É mais sobre a curiosidade de saber como as coisas funcionam, sabe de algum link explicando isso ou o próprio código para que eu possa tentar entender?

Comment: Pode começar estudando o código dos próprios módulos que já usa. Deve ter no Github.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso mas os modulos que eu uso utilizam de outros módulos para realizar a conexão, sabe de algum módulo que não utilize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Sem os módulos", em Python, você pode usar todos as funções que são embutidas (builtin): no caso do Python isso significa que você ainda pode se comunicar com o mundo usando print, input, e até abrir e escrever em qualquer arquivo com o open.

Isso é muito mais do que dá pra fazer em algumas linguagens. 
Os módulos que acompanham a biblioteca padrão do Python são parte integral da linguagem, e podem ser considerados sempre disponíveis. E nesse aspecto, Python historicamente é uma das linguagens melhor servida para dezenas de casos de uso. A única exceção seria se você quisesse rodar seu programa um ambiente em que espaço em disco seja muito restrito, e nesse caso, queira customizar um Python com apenas parte da biblioteca padrão: essa customização levaria, em casos normais, semanas para ser feita de forma a se garantir que você não vai quebrar outras funcionalidades da linguagem -  e mesmo assim, valeria a pena pensar em usar uma implementação alternativa como o micro-python.

Em outras palavras: para todos os efeitos, você *não* faz o comunicação com sockets, ou networking de HTTP sem os módulos da biblioteca padrão. E isso é o *normal* em todas as linguagens - mesmo em C você tem que incluir o `<stdio.h>` para usar o printf e open.

Aliás, ao contrário, de alguns anos para cá, com melhoria dos processos de gerenciamento de pacotes (que está longe de ser perfeito ainda), é considerado que instalar um pacote terceiro -  de fora da biblioteca padrão - não deveria ser uma barreira. Isso implica por exemplo, que é tão prático fazer uso da biblioteca externa `requests`, que simplifica em uma ordem de grandeza o uso de HTTP pelo seu programa, quanto usar direto o urllib e http.client., que acompanham o Python.

## E como os módulos fazem isso?

Independente da linguagem de programação, a única coisa que pode dar recursos de comunicação com a rede, ou com a tela (os pixels, não o terminal), ou outros periféricos, como webcans, microfone, etc... é o sistema operacional. O Kernel vai disponibilizar chamadas específicas
que vão construir "sockets": uma estrutura de dados nativa na memória, que é gerenciada quando chegam dados novos, pelo próprio kernel do S.O. 
Os próprios sistemas operacionais tem uma camada de bibliotecas fundamentais, que fazem a ponte com essas chamadas do kernel - dessa
forma, qualquer programa que possa fazer uma chamada em código nativo,
seguindo as convenções de chamada dessas bibliotecas, pode usar todos
os serviços que o Kernel do sistema expõe (e para os quais o usuário atual tenha permissões).

Para alguns periféricos, mesmo no Windows,  o periférico é exposto como um pseudo arquivo. É o caso de impressoras antigas, por exemplo - no Windows ficavam expostas com o nome de arquivo "prn". No Linux, em "/dev/lp0" ou algum outro nome - escrever dados nesses arquivos podia enviar os bytes direto para a impressora. Portas seriais, mesmo as criadas por emulação com dispositivos USB ainda funcionam dessa forma.  Ou seja, para essa classe de periféricos, apenas ler e escrever no arquivo correspondente pode estabelecer a comunicação com os mesmos - sem a linguagem ou o programador terem que saber mais detalhes da biblioteca de baixo nível que eu mencionei acima.

E voltnado a essa biblioteca: ela é a que tem as funções que aparecem para a linguagem C nos cabeçalhos `stdio.h` e `stdlib.h`, dentre outros. Ou seja, mesmo para ler e escrever arquivos, a história é a mesma: seu programa chama essas bibliotecas de baixo nível (as funções open, read e write, etc... nelas),  que fazem a ponte com o Kernel para efetivamente executar as operações.

Em Python, os módulos que já temos fazem a ponte com essa biblioteca do C. Isso é feito por técnicas diferentes: os módulos podem ser escritos eles mesmos em C - e compilados para módulos Python - esse é o jeito fundamental de expor chamadas em código nativo para Python: vocẽ escreve um código em C que inclui o cabeçalho "Python.h", e preenche algumas estruturas de dados para dizer quais das suas funções em C serão visíveis do Python, e que parâmetros aceitam, o que retornam, etc... A documentação para isso está aqui:
https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html . E é assim que os módulos da biblioteca padrão funcionam. Em outras linguagens, tem que existir algo equivalente - no final das contas, todos tem que fazer as chamadas pela "glibc" (no caso do GNU/Linux, mas não do Linux rodando como kernel do Android, por exemplo) - No Windows acredito que as chamadas estejam na "system32.dll". Isso,como você pode perceber, é bastante trabalhoso, mas é o "como é feito". A documentação completa da glibc está aqui: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html (inclusive com todos os conceitos e a documentação sobre como criar sockets)

Em Python existem outras formas de chamar as funççoes direto em C, incluindo as funções da glibc - que podem criar sockets, ler e escrever direto em arquivos, etc... Uma delas é o módulo "ctypes", que permite que você possa configurar e chamar diretoas funções ali. Por exemplo, aluns anos atŕas, alguém precisava usar a funcionalidade `sync`, que faz o flush de todos os arquivos abertos para o disco, fisicamente, de dentro do Python. A funcionalidade ainda não existia no Python (mas foi incluida depois disso, no Python 3.3 no módulo `os`, como `os.sync()`) - então respondi com a receita para chamar a função direto na glibc:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983272/does-python-have-sync/15983693#15983693

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> libc.sync()
0
```

Nesse caso é bem simples por que a função sync não recebe nem retorna nenhum parâmetro. Para coisas como sockets, etc... o kernel retorna estruturas de dados complexas, e tudo isso tem que ser registrado com código usando ctypes, para que você possa usar essas funçoes.

Além de escrever direto com a cpython api  e usar o ctypes, há várias outras formas - desde geradores automáticos de ligação para bibliotecas em código nativo, como swig e boost, até o "cython" que compila código Python direto para código nativo, podendo chamar funções em C.

E essa é a história de como os módulos "falam" com o sistema.

Para coisas como a urllib, não tem segredo: a funcionalidade em baixo nível é dos sockets - para construir e usar o protocolo http por cima disso, é possível fazer com Python puro, atuando nos dados recebidos e a enviar, é só checar as especificações. Alguns módulos vão fazer isso em código nativo (em geral em C), por questões de performance. è só saber usar bytes, struct, bytearray e seguir as especificações.

## E para programas que aparecem na tela, em sua própria janela?

Para objetos como criar janelas, por exemplo: o Kernel vai expor interfaces de como mudar o modo de video e mapear áreas da memória para áreas da tela - ou vai expor chamadas para a GPU que copiem dados da memória para um retângulo na tela.  O sistema operacional vai expor chamadas em mais alto nível que tenham APIs de desenho, e, principalmente, para renderizar texto. No caso do Linux, essas APIs são o X11 que está em mudança para o Wayland. No windows, tem que checar a documentação -
Então perceba que mesmo assim, criar um programa em uma janela com uma área de texto ainda seria **bem** complicado. As mesmas bibliotecas expçoe chamadas direto para "criar uma janela", e uma área de texto já com alguma funcionalidade - e mesmo assim essas chamadas seriam fundamentalmente diferentes entre Windows, Linux e Mac OS (e mesmo entre Windows 7 e Windows 10). Ai que entram os "toolkits gráficos" - como GTK+, Qt e Tkinter, que cuidam das diferenças entre os sistemas por baixo do capô para nós.

## Funcionalidade mínima sem acessar as bibliotecas do sistema

Como em Python você tem acesso ao `open` e toda funcionalidade de arquivos, seria possível, em teoria, nos sistemas Unix (incluindo Linux, Android e MacOS), fazer o uso de sockets sem importar nenhum módulo. Mas um pouco de pesquisa mostra que provavelmente não seria possível criar um socket pra começar, e, se for, você nã o vai ter acesso direto as APIs específicas para sockets, tendo que criar workarounds para as situações mais comuns.

Para outros protocolos além de sockets crus, você teria ainda que re-implementar o protocolo inteiro só com o seu código (por exemplo, uma parte significativa do HTTP 1.1), só para "não ter que importar o módulo"). É uma situação pra lá de irracional - equivalente a querer construir um carro na sua garagem, a partir de parafusos, só para não ter que pegar um táxi (ou, no caso, para não ter que sair com seu próprio carro, já existente, tendo em vista que os módulos já estão lá)

Comment: eu entendi essa questão de que usando os módulos é bem mais prático e segue aquele lema de não reinventar a roda, era apenas uma questão de curiosidade para saber como funciona

Comment: expandi bem a resposta agora.